# Problem in Access Token Authorization Code Flow with Angular and .NET

Tags: .net, angular, authorization, access-token, auth0

I'm wring an client server application with Angular and .NET 6 to implement Autherization and Autherization with Auth0.
Here I'm following **Authorization Code Flow**
These are the steps that I have followed.

1. created Single page Application with Angular and added Auth0 login.
2. I logged in and fetched the access token from “getAccessTokenSilently()” method.
   when I checked with jwt.io, it says Invalid Signature.
3. Then I tried with idTokenClaims$ like this

```
this.auth.idTokenClaims$.subscribe(idToken => {
      console.log('Id Token: ', idToken);
      this.accessToken = idToken?.__raw;
    });
```

4. Then no issue from jwt.io.
5. I realized that the problem is with **Audience**
6. Then I tried with following way to add Audience and fetch the access token

```
this.auth.getAccessTokenSilently({ detailedResponse: true, authorizationParams:       {audience:'https://localhost:7181/'} }).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('Token Object: ', res);
        // console.log(res);
        //my code
      },
      (err) => {
        // console.log(err);
        console.log('Token Error: ', err);
      }
    );
```

But it doesen't work. After adding **Audience**, it is not calling to Auth0 side.

my Auth0 npm version is 2.2.1.

How can I overcome this issue? Have something missed from my end?

I tried with going through Auth0 documentation and Auth0 support community. But still no luck. In documentation also it is not describing with my tech stack.